# how to retrive crm attribute value with linq when bool is set to false or true

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, linq-to-entities, dynamics-crm-2011

[image]

```
 var emailAddress = xrmContext.ftr_EmailAddressSet
 .Where(e => e.ftr_EmailAddressId == emailAddressId 
          && e.ftr_IsDeleted == false))
   .Select(e => e.ftr_EmailAddress1).FirstOrDefault();
```

The above image is a crm entity and I need to retrieve emailaddress when "Is Deleted" option is "false(No)". I need and tried using a linq query in my C# .cs file.
When I use my code it returns a null value. When I remove this line:

```
e.ftr_IsDeleted == false
```

it returns emails with true and false correctly but I need it to work for only false.

Comment: What type is xrmContext.ftr_EmailAddressSet

Comment: Any chance you flipped the No and Yes values for boolean?

Answer (score 0):

Try using two where conditions like this:

```
  var emailAddress = xrmContext.ftr_EmailAddressSet.Where(e => e.ftr_EmailAddressId == emailAddressId).Where(e.ftr_IsDeleted == false).Select(e => e.ftr_EmailAddress1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope this helps.